# Simple Container Toolchain - failed to deploy : Exceeded maximum number of retries

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I'm trying to run the deploy pipeline created by the Simple Container Toolchain example.  The output of the deployment log is:

```
...
2017-07-03 15:49:43 UTC : creating group: /tmp/extension_content/cf ic group create --name hello-containers-XXXX_2 --publish 80 --desired 2 --min 1 --max 6 registry.ng.bluemix.net/chstest/hello-containers-XXXX:1
OK
The creation of the container group was requested.
The container group "hello-containers-XXXX_2" (ID: YYYY) was created.
Minimum container instances: 1
Maximum container instances: 6
Desired container instances: 2
2017-07-03 15:49:49 UTC : hello-containers-XXXX_2 is 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'
2017-07-03 15:49:53 UTC : hello-containers-XXXX_2 is 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'
...
... CREATE_IN_PROGRESS message repeated about 150 times
...
2017-07-03 16:02:51 UTC : hello-containers-XXXX_2 is 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'
2017-07-03 16:02:55 UTC : hello-containers-XXXX_2 is 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'
2017-07-03 16:02:58 UTC : Create group is not completed and stays in status 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'
2017-07-03 16:02:58 UTC : Failed to deploy group
To send notifications, set SLACK_WEBHOOK_PATH or HIP_CHAT_TOKEN in the environment

Finished: FAILED
```

If I navigate to the container dashboard in Bluemix, I see the following error log:

```
Group failed
Resource CREATE failed: ResourceInError: resources.asg.resources.i2jghszuv3br.resources.server: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance ZZZZ. Last exception: [u'Traceback (most recent call last): \n', u' File "/opt/bbc/openstack-12.1.90/nova/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, Code: 500"
```

How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a Bluemix support ticket against the Containers SRE Team. Do this by logging into your Bluemix account and in the upper right hand corner there is an option for "Support" = "Add Ticket".